# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric while saving decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to save decimal value in DB but getting this error.

The value I'm trying to save `0.00038711029163348665` or `1.00038711029163348665` or `2.00038711029163348665`, and column in DB is `Decimal(18,18)` not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: You need to read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and understand precision and scale

Answer (score 3):

The precision `DECIMAL(18,18)` means 18 *total* units of precision, all 18 of which come *after* the decimal point.  You need at least one unit of precision to the *left* of the decimal point to handle the whole number components of the input, so you should be using `DECIMAL(19,18)`, or something similar.

[See the demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b5625350e78913d1c3fecbcb9e0f894e) to verify that `DECIMAL(19,18)` resolves your problem, at least for the data you showed us.

Answer (score 2):

`Decimal(18,18)` has 18 digits to the right of the decimal place and none to the left, so `1.00038711029163348665` doesn't fit.

Use a larger type.  Why not just use `decimal(38, 18)`?